# How to set basepath/prefix in Loopback 4?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, v4l2loopback

I want to set basepath to my application. I updated with

```
await app.restServer.basePath('/api/v1');
```

in my `"index.js"` at my project root folder. But when I'm trying to access the explorer, throwing errors as **"Cant get explorer"**.

```
    await app.basePath('/api/v1'); 
       await app.restServer.basePath('/api/v1');
     this.static('/', path.join(__dirname, '../public'));
this.bind(RestBindings.SequenceActions.SEND).toProvider(Validateprovider);
        this.bind(RestExplorerBindings.CONFIG).to({
          path: path.resolve('/explorer'),
        });
```

Once the application is loaded, am able to access this URL: http://127.0.0.1:8020/api/v1
But when I click on explorer in the same page. Its not redirecting to explorer, instead giving error as

> "   Cannot GET /explorer/"

Please let me know how to access explorer with the prefix which I have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this in application.ts.

```
this.bind(RestExplorerBindings.CONFIG).to({
  path: '/api/v1',
});
```

For more details, you can refer to the doc [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/packages/rest-explorer/README.md).

Comment: No Samarpan, this is not the one. When am trying to access, the explorer is not at all opening.  However, thank you for the solution.

Comment: If you can share some more code , basically the application.ts, then, I might help.

Answer (score 2):

problem probably is, that in `/publix/index.html` link to the explorer has not changed, and it points to `/explorer`. After changing base path you should change this link to `{your new base path}/explorer`. Changing the base path in the app does not update static resources. Basically, in `index.html` you should have:

```html
<h3>API Explorer: <a href="/api/v1/explorer">/explorer</a></h3>
```

then it will work